# postsharp applytostatemachine false does not work with web api

Tags: postsharp

I am using postsharp express.  We are using async web api's.  The documentation for postsharp says that setting ApplyToStateMachine = false will be backwards compatible however we are finding that it is breaking the web api pipeline.  When I apply an aspect to my controller method marked with async I get the following exception (note that my controller method fully returns correctly).

InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

As soon as I take the aspect off it works just fine.

Even though its advertised as being backwards compatible does this mean that its not in all cases and can break the application and that I need to buy the professional version?

Comment: The backward compatibility here means that the code with *ApplyToStateMachine = false* works the same way as it would in the previous version of PostSharp (3.0). Most probably the code of your aspect is executed at the incorrect point of time with regard to the async code. Could you add the source code of the aspect to your question?

Comment: yeah I had found the problem.  there was an errant async void method being called.